# Invalid datetime format: 1366 Incorrect integer value:

Tags: php, laravel

This is my controller  and columns type is int(11) in database

```
 $req['date_time'] = ($req->date_time) ? Carbon::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $req->date_time)->timestamp : '0';
                $req['publish_date'] = ($req->publish_date) ? Carbon::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $req->publish_date)->timestamp : '0';
                $req['expiration_date'] = ($req->expiration_date) ? Carbon::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $req->expiration_date)->timestamp : '0';
                CmsArticle::create($req->all());
```

Comment: during edit the date it  is working but  not in storing

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure all the columns are integers? SQL Server returns that error when an invalid value is used where a `datetime` type is needed.

Perhaps the value `0` shouldn't be used, and instead insert a null or a special date far in the past?

Comment: my requirement is  to save 0 as default